# putting 2 images side by side with no space and centered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get 2 images that are side by side centered on the page and I am completely lost. I've included align="center" in div and it does nothing and I have tried positioning absolute and it kicks that image to center but other is still margined left. I have included my code below for you to see. I'm sure it's fairly easy and my brain is just stuck clocking today. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
<div>
   <div class="item">
     <contentful-image url="@Model.EventImages[0].File.Url" @*width="300" height="300" *@ style="float:left; width: 30%; margin-bottom: 0.5em; position: absolute " />
   </div>  
   <div class="item">
     <contentful-image url="@Model.EventImages[1].File.Url" @*width="300" height="300"*@ style="float:left; width: 30%; margin-bottom: 0.5em";/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ..and the first rule of centering is **"Don't use float!"**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try these two examples and see if any solves your problem, though presented with the `img` element.

If you want the `body` element to be the parent, you can do something like this:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100vw;height:100vh}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Add this if you want to place them horizontally. */
/*
div {
  display: flex;
}
*/

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="img1">
 </div>  
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="img2">
 </div>
</div>
```

And if you want the `div` to be the parent, like this:

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}
html, body {width:100vw;height:100vh}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* flex-direction: column; */ /*  Add this if you want to place them vertically. */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="img1">
 </div>  
 <div class="item">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300" alt="img2">
 </div>
</div>
```

Where the `.parent` takes full width & height of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS class instead of inline CSS your CSS goes as follows:

CSS for image tag:

```
.myImg {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px; 
}
```

CSS for the div you have to contain the image:

```
.image-container{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now the CSS to centre your image:

```
#image{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Finally how to use it in html:

```
<div id="images">
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="myImg" alt="No image" src="your_image_url"/>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="myImg" alt="No image" src="your_image_url"/>
</div>
</div>​
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.myImg {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 30px; 
}
.image-container{
 display: inline-block
}
#images{
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="images">
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="myImg" alt="No image" src="http://shlesha.co.in/images/demo/logo/logo-blue-white-trans-249x80.png"/>
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="myImg" alt="No image" src="http://shlesha.co.in/images/demo/logo/logo-blue-white-trans-249x80.png"/>
</div>
</div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Here "display: inline-block" helps you to display two or more images to be displayed side by side and margin as auto helps you to automatically adjust your margin irrespective of the screen size

I hope this solves your need for any further query comment below.

Answer (score -1):

try using flex-box, it's pretty straight forward. Set display:flex for the parent, then you can align the children with align-items: center.
html like:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="item">
       <contentful-image url="" />
   </div>  
   <div class="item">
       <contentful-image url="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

and css like:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try creating parent and child div like this:

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.child-container{
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
<div class="child-container">
 <img alt="First Image" src=""/>
</div>
<div class="child-container">
 <img alt="Second Image" src="" />
</div>
</div>
```